# What is a good way to ensure that underlying streams for Jersey's StreamingOutput gets closed?

Tags: jersey, response, inputstream, resource-cleanup

I'm working on a REST API and I'm using Jersey for this. One of the endpoints are returning files, and I'm using `StreamingOut` for this.

```
final InputStream is = getInputStreamFor(fileHandle);           
StreamingOutput so = new StreamingOutput() {
  @Override
  public void write(OutputStream os) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
    try {
      IOUtils.copy(is, os);    
      os.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw e;
    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
  }
}

return Response
.ok(rs)
.build();
```

As far as I've figured out; what happens here is that I return the `Response` from my method, and from there Jersey starts writing the `InputStream` to the `OutputStream` by invoking `write(OutputStream os)` method. That is, the `write(OutputStream os)` is invoked after my method.

Now, what if something goes wrong before Jersey gets to the point of invoking `write(OutputStream os)`? The `InputStream` will never be closed.

Should I keep track of all `InputStream` instances I hand over to a `Response`, and attempt to close them after, say, 5 minutes to be certain that everything gets cleaned up nicely?

I do not like the thought of handing out `InputStream` instances, which Jersey by the way have no way of knowing how to close, and not being able to ensure myself that everything gets cleaned up.